# How to create a Texture and mix nodes in the compositor with python

Tags: python, compositing-nodes

I would like to create a mix and texture node in the compositor with python.

Here is my code:

```
import bpy
import os

from bpy import context, data, ops

#*******************Texture********************************* 
#Creation of a new texture
bpy.ops.texture.new()

#Give a name to the texture
bpy.data.textures["Noise"].name = "Noise"

#Define the type of texture, here noise
bpy.data.textures["Noise"].type = 'NOISE'

#*****************Compositing ******************************  
#To have more light on the picture and something more realistic
bpy.context.scene.view_settings.view_transform = 'Standard'

#Switch on nodes and get reference
bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
tree       = bpy.context.scene.node_tree

#Clear default node
for node in tree.nodes:
    tree.nodes.remove(node)

#Creation of the input, where the image is loading
image_node          = tree.nodes.new(type='CompositorNodeImage') #  Create a new image node
image_node.location = 0,0

#Create mix node 
mix_node = tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeGroup')
mix_node.location = 0,0

#Create texture node 
texture_node            = tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texture_node.location   = 0,100
texture_node.texture    = bpy.data.textures["Noise"]


#Creation of the final node (Compose = storage of the final result)
comp_node          = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeComposite')   
comp_node.location = 400,0

path  = 'D:/Documents/Cours/PhD/2A/Validation Blender model/Behave as the reality/Same model Simulation and Reality/Triangle pattern/3.5m/'

image_name = 'image name'
img_path   = path + image_name

#Loading the image
img = bpy.data.images.load(img_path, check_existing=True)  

#The image is put as the input of the node
image_node.image = img

#*****************Link nodes***************************
links = tree.links
#links.new(image_node.outputs[0], comp_node.inputs[0])
links.new(image_node.outputs[0], mix_node.inputs[1])
links.new(texture_node.outputs[1], mix_node.inputs[2])
links.new(mix_nodel.outputs[0], comp_node.inputs[0])
```

When I run my script I have on error on the creation of the mix and texture node.
I check on the internet, and I found nothing.
How can I fix that.

PS: I did not put the picture I am using. You can use one of yours.

Comment: You use `'ShaderNodeGroup'` for creating mix while it should be `'CompositorNodeMixRGB'`. And the same is with Texture, it should be `'CompositorNodeImage'` if you need an Image Texture or `'CompositorNodeTexture'` if you need a noise texture. You can find out proper names with Python Console autocomplete, they are detemined in `.bl_idname` attribute of each node.

Comment: It works.
Thanks a lot